# Wordpress Tags: Turn Dashes into Spaces? (

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

when entering tags into wordpress, spaces aren't allowed so is it possible enter a tag as "Word1-Word2" and turn that into "Word1 Word2" when it is displayed on the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php
in a filter or straight in yr theme

Comment: what do you mean by in a filter or straight into my theme?

Comment: you can look up wp filters to see what i mean or you can just add the code in the template files